# Magento: addSuccess() In an External Script Not Saving Properly

Tags: magento

I've got an external script (not within magento). I'm trying to figure out why this message is not being shown on the cart page...

```
    <?php 
            require_once '../app/Mage.php';
            umask(0);
            Mage::app();    

            [...]

            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess("Stuff just happened");
            header('Location: http://example.com/checkout/cart');
    ?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try adding to the checkout/session singleton

Comment: I actually got it to work by adding this to the top of the script: Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
 Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');